# Probability of a pencil without an eraser.

Tags: probability

Pencil case holds 30 pencils. Probability of pulling out a yellow one is 0.4, probability of pulling out a yellow one with an eraser is 0.3

How many pencils without erasers are in the case?

Here is what I think is the solution, is it correct?

Given:
P(E|Y)=0.3
P(Y)=0.4

Find $P(\bar E)$

Solution:
Events are independent. So $P(E|Y)=P(E)$? Does that mean $P(\bar E) = 0.7$ and thus there are $0.7*30=21$ pencils without erasers in the case?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: This question is also missing information. The answer could be anywhere between 3 and 21.

Comment: Yes, I apologize, I didn't realize I'll get answers so quick! I added my solution. Why do you think it could be in that range? This is all the information I got for that question.

Comment: Are all pencils with eraser yellow? Or are all non-yellow pencils with eraser? Besides, I did not see a reason why the probability is conditional.

Comment: I didn't say anywhere it was conditional. $P(E|Y)$ means probability that a pencil has an eraser and is yellow I thought. I am not sure what you are asking @ShiyuLiang Please correct mathematical notation if not correct

Comment: @InterstellarProbe can you show me how you got that range? I am pretty sure this is all the info I got for the question, I am interested to see how you think about it.

Comment: People normally use $P(B|A)$ to denote the probability of B under condition A. I think what you intended to say is the probability that both $A$ and $B$ happen, which is the product probability $P(AB)$. You may take a look at this. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability

Comment: Reading what you wrote, it appears that $P(E\cap Y) = 0.3$, which is different from $P(E|Y)$. The first is the probability that you pick a pencil that both has an eraser and is yellow. The latter is the event that you pick a pencil with an eraser given that the pencil you pick is yellow. Very different probabilities. I assumed $P(E\cap Y)=0.3$. In that case, there are $30\times 0.3=9$ pencils that are yellow with an eraser. There are $0.4\times 30 = 12$ pencils that are yellow. So, any of the 18 non-yellow pencils may or may not have erasers. Plus the 3 yellow pencils with no eraser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume picking up each pencil is equally probable.

$$N(yellow\ pencils) = N(pencils)P(A) = 12;$$
$$N(yellow\ pencils\ with\ eraser) = N(pencils)P(B) = 9;$$
$$N(yellow\ pencils\ without\ eraser) = 3;$$
where $N$ denotes the number, $A$ picking a yellow pencil, $B$ picking a yellow pencil with eraser.

For the other 18 non-yellow pencils, if no additional information is given, they can be either with or without eraser, so $$3\leq N(pencils\ without\ eraser)\leq 21.$$

Comment: the additional information *seems to be* that "with eraser" and $yellow color$ are independent